# Javascript -> redirect by select and pick selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, select

i have in index.html this code:

```
 <select id="myselect" class="form-control"  ONCHANGE="location.href = 'drzave.html'">
        <option selected disabled>Odabir:</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
      </select>
```

When i change it,  it redirect on drzave.html. In drzave.html i have included data.js with code:

```
var test = $( "#myselect" ).val();
    console.log(test)
```

I'm trying to get selected value on index.html , but i receive undefined message.

Thanks, Tomislav

Comment: You want the selected option to be passed through/ available to the page drzave.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont be able to get the `#mySelect` selected value in any other page than `index.html`.

To achieve what you want, the best way is by saving the selected value to the [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). E.g:

```
<select id="myselect" class="form-control">
  <option selected disabled>Odabir:</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
<script>
  document.getElementById('myselect').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('myselect', this.value);
    location.href = 'drzave.html';
  });
</script>
```

And then, in your `drzave.html` page, you can get the value by doing:

```
var test = sessionStorage.getItem('myselect');
console.log(test);
```

Other ways are:

- Saving to the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- Passing through queryString.

Probably there are other ways, but I don't think any of them will be better.

I've [created a plnkr for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/i7opSjmF81Zt2jC0uM49?p=preview) to show the usability.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the selected option's value passed through to the page drzave.html?

If so, you would

```js
function redirectFunction() {
  window.location.replace ('drzave.html?myselect=' + $('#dropDownId').val())
  // then on landing page you will have to parse this value out of the querystring
  // or you could use cookies to set the value to the next page (google jquery.cookie)
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myselect").on("change", redirectFunction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="myselect" class="form-control">
  <option selected disabled>Odabir:</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```